# HTML scraping - How to find business category in a yelp business page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, yelp

Given a yelp local [listing](http://www.yelp.com/biz/ucsf-medical-center-at-mount-zion-san-francisco), which part should I be looking for to fetch the business category (Restaurants, Hospital, etc).

I do not want to use an API, I'm looking to crawl a HTML page and extract this data.

Comment: use the api anyway  :)  yelp will be displeased if you do this and might block your ip.

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree with @Eevee about using the API, by scraping you are probably violating their terms and conditions.

If you want to crawl a webiste use scrapy (http://scrapy.org/)

Just analyze the page to see which elements you need and how it is the most efficient to get to them and just write the crawler